# Android - How to make a project depend on another

Tags: java, android, dependencies

I'm super overwhelmed with the tons of information out there and my issue is a pretty simple one.

I have made a project in IntelliJ Idea which has a package called `com.example.util`. In this package, I've got some static classes that I want to use in other projects.

Now, I have an Android Project and I want to use the classes in that util package.

However, I can't find an easy way that allows me to keep a flow state editing the two projects (Android and Util). I can compile the util package into a single JAR file and then copy-paste it inside the `libs` folder in Android but that's too much work and not efficient.

Can someone explain me this? All I want is to keep writing on the Util package and have the Android project pull all the classes.

Comment: Have any of these answers answered your question? If so, please consider accepting the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can put the classes you want to use in a library: [Create multiple projects in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862237/create-multiple-projects-in-android-studio)

Here is a little snippet from an answer in the above post describing how to add your library to the project:

> In settings.gradle of project add
>
> ```
> include ':commonLibrary'
> project(':commonLibrary').projectDir= new File('../path_to_your_library_module')
> ```
>
> In build.gradle add
>
> ```
> compile project(':commonLibrary').
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Go to File,
Click New - Import Module
Add the downloaded project
After importing, right click on your project and select Open Module Settings
In Modules section, select app, go to dependencies tab, press '+' and select Module dependency. Done!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35223130/6060743

Or

https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio (follow method-2 till step 7)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.  On your gradle build within the "dependecies" block add the line:

```
compile project(":path:myproject")
```

Comment: Meta: `compile` is deprecated and removed in Gradle 7; use `implementation` instead.