# Flutter how to setup Android Studio when developing multiple projects

Tags: flutter, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have three projects, one common widget package and two applications.  I have the following directory structure

- widgets (pubspec.yaml, lib/, ..)
- app1 (pubspec.yaml, lib/, ..)
- app2 (pubspec.yaml, lib/, ..)

I can open them in three separate AndroidStudio windows but this has some drawbacks.  A refactoring in eg widgets (eg renaming a widget or a function name) is not applied to app1 or app2.

So I'm wondering whether it is possible to open the three projects in a single AndroidStudio window so that refactoring is applied to all projects

Comment: I don't think you can do this!

Comment: Might indeed be the correct answer. I'm sure I'm not the only one with this problem so I'm wondering how others tackle this and how their setup looks like.

Comment: Try checking this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/32862637/5882307

Comment: Thanks for the link!  However, this only works when developing for Android I guess.

Comment: Although something similar is possible by using  "File/Project structure...", select "Modules" and click "+" and point to the iml file of the module you depend on.    This is certainly an improvement though a refactoring in a common library that impacts multiple applications still has to be done manually in the other applications.

Comment: @OMiShah Your comment pointed me in the right direction so if you convert it to an answer, I can reward you the bounty.

Comment: Thank you for your generosity, but no thanks. I think you can reward me sometimes later or to somebody else. ;) @MarcVanDaele

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it is possible to have multiple 'modules' open in AndroidStudio where a module can be either a Flutter application or a Flutter package.  Hence it is perfectly possible to have the 'widgets' and 'app1'/'app2' open in a single window.  This can be done by using "File/Project structure...", select "Modules" and click "+" and point to the iml file of the module you want to add.

Comment: this will create a new module what about if I already have the projects under the same root directory and I want to open them as a workspace or enable Android studio to understand there are 3 projects under root directory to be easy switch between them

Answer (score 1):

Open the top folder with the 3 projects and then `File/Project Structure...`. Here, add all project folders with `+ Add Content Root`:

[image: Project structure >> Add Content Root]

Then your Android Studio sidebar should list the different projects individually:

[image: Project overview]

Editing something (e.g. method name) in one project changes it in the other ones and you can use Flutter Dev Tools from Android Studio (which does not work if you simply open the top folder with Android Studio).

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [How do I open two or more projects at the same time in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420247/how-do-i-open-two-or-more-projects-at-the-same-time-in-android-studio).

Try to go to Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings,
in the Project Opening section,
choose Open project in new window.

Comment: If I open them in different windows, a refactoring in one window (eg renaming a widget method) will not have effect in the other window using this widget